# Linq to entity Check if date of birth is between given set of date ranges(EF6)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to filter records from person table where the Dob field(Date) is in any one of multiple date ranges input by user
...

```
 List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> dateranges=.......;

    var filtered=context.Person.Where (x=>dateranges.Any(y=>x.Dob>y.Item1 && x.Dob< y.Item2));
```

This throws an exception

```
    "Unable to process the type 'System.Tuple`2[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089], because it has no known mapping to the 
value layer."
```

Any Idea what is the best way to handle this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a carefully crafted query which jumps between Linq to EF and Linq to Objects.

```
List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> dateranges=.......;
IEnumerable<IQueryable<Person>> queries = from d in dateranges
                                         let startDate = d.Item1
                                         let endDate = d.Item2
              select (context.Person.Where(p => p.Birthday >= startDate && p.Birthday <= enDate));
IQueryable<Person> query = queries.Aggregate(Queryable.Concat);
```

I must add however that this is not very efficient in terms of EF query planner nor SQL server query planner. You will likely find perf issues with indices on this approach.

It would be perhaps more efficient to use EntityFramework.Extended's `.Future()`.

```
List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> dateranges=.......;
List<FutureQuery<Person>> queries = from d in dateranges
                                         let startDate = d.Item1
                                         let endDate = d.Item2
              select (context.Person.Where(p => p.Birthday >= startDate && p.Birthday <= enDate).Future()).ToList();
IEnumerable<Person> query = queries.SelectMany(x =>);
```